# How do I programmatically add a TextView in a Linear Layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-linearlayout

I have an app developed in Kotlin that uses a linear layout in which I want to insert several TextViews.
Since the number of TextViews can change, I would like to add them dynamically in code and not just edit them on the layout file.

Comment: Do you want to change them by Updating your apps? or You want to change them from database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mTextView = TextView(this)
mTextView.setText("your text")
findViewById(R.id.yourlinearlayout).addView(mTextView)
```

But i'm pretty sure that this is not the best solution for you, you should look at what is a RecyclerView and it's purpose.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the tip, I will definitely have a look at the RecyclerView.